Calculating pairwise p values for multiple variables in R
I need help comparing 8 different drug conditions using the same assay. my data is very simple but i cannot come up with a smart way to do this. Currently it looks like this:



Drug
Result




Drug1
0.5


Drug1
0.2


Drug2
0.4


Drug2
0.5


Drug3
0.4


Drug3
0.5



Etc. Each drug has about 30-40 read outs and there are 8 drugs. I want to create a box and whisker plot which I did with ggplot and include significant p values when comparing each condition against all other conditions in a pairwise fashion. Can anyone help?
Thx!
I tried to do this in ggplot using ggpubr with stat_compare_means and it was too hard to compare different results alll at once.

So what exactly is the desired output? What do you want the plot to look like?

I believe the best advice would be to recommend you review the question. Share the actual data or a subset of the data, or even mock data that can actually be reproduced, as code. You can use dput(data), and paste the output in the question. This question is also missing the definition of 'comparing each condition agains each other'. Do you wish to compare the means/distributions?
How do you wish to calculate these? Wih t tests?
Do you wish to test all combinations of drugs against each other?
That would likely be better done with a proper test that compares multiple groups, like an ANOVA

This is clear enough that two people felt they could answer it.  I am voting to reopen.

This may be a good case for the ggbetweenstats function in the ggstatsplot package, which is an extension of ggplot2. The will simultaneously perform the pairwise comparisons and plot.
Generating some sample data:
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Drug = c(rep("A", 333), rep("B", 333), rep("C", 334)),
                 Result = c(runif(333), runif(333, max = 3), runif(334, max = 10)))

Plotting, with pairwise comparisons:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstatsplot)

ggbetweenstats(data = df, x = Drug, y = Result)

Output:

There is a lot of customizability, including the specific pairwise test to be performed (see ?ggbetweenstats), but if you only want the box-and-whisker and remove the violin, you could do:
ggbetweenstats(data = df, x = Drug, y = Result),
                violin.args = list(width = NA, na.rm = TRUE))

Which gives:


Assuming the input data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we can use boxplot as shown.
There is a warning with this small data but if your aim is to compare drugs then you will need the notches since the notches give a way to do approximate tests for statistical difference, viz. if the notches overlap then the null hypothesis of no difference between such pairs cannot be rejected.
The code here uses base R so no packages are needed.
boxplot(Result ~ Drug, data = dat, notch = TRUE)
## Warning message:
## In (function (z, notch = FALSE, width = NULL, varwidth = FALSE,  :
##   some notches went outside hinges ('box'): maybe set notch=FALSE

(continued after graph)

Also consider running TukeyHSD to look at pairwise comparisons.  This automatically handles the global confidence level rather than using it separately for each comparison automatically handling the problem that if we were to do repeated separate tests at a 95% confidence level then 5% of those tests would be significant by chance even in the absence of any true significance.  In this case we already know from the summary output p value that none of the differences are significant but if your actual data is larger you may need TukeyHSD.  The help file for TukeyHSD and this wikipedia article provide more information.
fm <- aov(Result ~ Drug, data = dat)
summary(fm)
##             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## Drug         2 0.0133 0.00667    0.36   0.72
## Residuals    3 0.0550 0.01833               
hsd <- TukeyHSD(fm); hsd

giving
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = Result ~ Drug, data = dat)

$Drug
                   diff      lwr     upr   p adj
Drug2-Drug1  1.0000e-01 -0.46581 0.66581 0.76057
Drug3-Drug1  1.0000e-01 -0.46581 0.66581 0.76057
Drug3-Drug2 -5.5511e-17 -0.56581 0.56581 1.00000

Note
dat <- data.frame(
  Drug = rep(c("Drug1", "Drug2", "Drug3"), each = 2L),
  Result = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5)
)

